# SharePoint initiation form dynamic approval list

Tags: workflow, form, approval

I want to create an initiation for for the following process:
1. User uploads excel file
2. User triggers workflow manually
3. Initiation form allows user to select 4 approvers from a drop-down list (Level 1, 2, 3,4)
4. User submits the file for approval to the following approvers.

All approvers have O365 accounts. I want to be able to dynamically update the list of different level approvers based on their names and not their emails. Regarding the levels of approvals, Level 4 can't approve before level 3, and level 3 can't before level 2, etc.